# Php function problems

Tags: php

I have problem with functions. I write them in config/funkcije.php. In folder config/ I have db.php which connects to database, etc... When I open in browser config/funkcije.php nothing shows on that page but it should echo out some results from DB.

This is my function:

```
include 'db.php';
function prikaz_posebne_ponude()
{

    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM posebna_ponuda ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $sql1 = $mysqli->query("$sql");
    while ($row = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $glavni_naziv = $row[$lang];
        if (empty($glavni_naziv)) {
            echo '';
        } else {

            echo "<div class='row-banner'>";
            echo "<h3><span>" . $langArray['rezervacija_smjestaja'] . "</span></h3>";
            echo "<p>" . $glavni_naziv . "</p>";
            echo "</div>";

        }
    }
}
```

But when I remove function prikaz_posebne_ponude(){ and } on the last line everything works fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: **Pro-tip:** Name your variables/functions in english

Comment: You need to make the `$mysqli` variable global: `global $mysqli;`, and `$langArray` by the look of it too.

Comment: The function most likely isn't being called.

Comment: Whats is in $lang where do you get $langArray from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **define** a function, but you never **call** it. Functions are reusable pieces of code, but to execute the contained statements, you have to **call** the function like this:

```
prikaz_posebne_ponude();
```

You also need to tell PHP that some variables are global (inside your function):

```
global $mysqli;
global $langArray;
global $lang;
```

Comment: I called it, but still, nothing happens! :S

Comment: @user3002173 Don't forget to add `global $mysqli; global $langArray; global $lang;` to your function.

Answer (score 2):

First, variables you use in functions that are defined outside the function need to be global:

```
function prikaz_posebne_ponude()
{

    global $mysqli;
    global $langArray;
   ....
}
```

Then, you need to **call** the function for it to run:

```
prikaz_posebne_ponude();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add at the end of this prikaz_posebne_ponude(); and you'll see the result.
A function is made as a piece of code to be called everytime you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse the necessary variables into the function:

```
function function_name ($con,$LangArray,$Lang){
  /*
     Manipulate here 
  */
}
```

or make them global:

```
function function_name(){
  global $mysqli;
  global $langArray;
  global $Lang;
}
```

then call:

```
 $LangArray = array("test","test_1");
 $Lang = "Value";
 $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","user","pass","db");
 function_name($mysqli,$LangArray,$Lang);
```